# Go: template without name

Tags: go

Is there a way to create a `template.Template` from a `string` without giving it a name?
Looking at the docs, it seems like the [New(name string)](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#New) is the only way to parse a template string. I wrote a helper function which generates a unique name using an iterator.

```
var seq chan int

func init() {
    seq = make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for i := 0; true; i++ {
            seq <- i
        }
    }()
}

func TemplateToString(tmplStr string, data interface{}) (string, error) {
    name := fmt.Sprintf("template-%d", <-seq)
    tmpl, err := template.New(name).Parse(tmplStr)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    buffer := bytes.Buffer{}
    err = tmpl.Execute(&buffer, data)
    return buffer.String(), err
}
```

[playground](http://play.golang.org/p/3W6IwEelR8)

This works, but I would prefer a cleaner approach if it's possible.

Comment: Strongly advise against ignoring those errors (even/especially in example code)

Comment: @Dustin I removed the checks for the sake of brevity.

Comment: I understand, but there's now another example on the internet of code that explicitly ignores errors, which is a direction slightly opposed to making the world a better place. You could at the least use `template.Must` here and should likely return an error from that function in general.  It's not necessarily more brief, but it is more likely to be copied and have someone be very confused as to why their program isn't working (due to, for example, an invalid template).

Comment: @Dustin enabling copy/paste coders isn't too high on my priority list. But feel free to edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `""` as the name for your immediate template.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [template.Template](//pkg.go.dev/text/template#Template) with
the `new` builtin:

```
package main

import (
   "os"
   "text/template"
)

func main() {
   t, err := new(template.Template).Parse("hello {{.}}\n")
   if err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }
   t.Execute(os.Stdout, "world")
}
```